# Solve this First Order Non-Linear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve $$y'=x\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\quad y(1)=\alpha \in\mathbb{R}$$

I'm not sure how to proceed . it's nonlinear and The method of Separation of Variables cannot  be   be possible.

by Cauchy Lipschitz , the Equation admits a local solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has an elementary solution. This is not a full answer but it is too long for a comment, and may be worth considering.

Try $y(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n(x-1)^n$ with $a_0=\alpha.$ Then,

$\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} na_n(x-1)^{n-1}\right)^2=x^2\left(x^2+\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n(x-1)^{n}\right)^2\right)$

so

$\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} na_n(x-1)^{n-1}-\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n(x-1)^{n}\right)\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} na_n(x-1)^{n-1}+\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n(x-1)^{n}\right)=x^4$

which is

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}((n+1)a_{n+1}-a_n)(x-1)^n\cdot \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}((n+1)a_{n+1}+a_n)(x-1)^n=x^4.$

Now expand as a Cauchy product to determine the coefficients and deal with the issue of convergence.

Comment: I am assuming the OP knows how to compute Cauchy products and equate coefficients, so I think he/she can finish from here. Of course, if they do not find my admittedly partial answer useful, I will be happy yo delete it. You will notice that on this site, many if not most answers leave some details to the OP. And lastly, .how would you approach this problem?

Comment: I agree with your idea but I see a problem since $a_1=\pm \sqrt{1+\alpha}$. Which one do we retain ?

Comment: I am getting $(a_1-\alpha)(a_1+\alpha)=0.$

Comment: @Matematleta I find your approach interesting, do not erase it, I'll do the calculations

Comment: @Matematleta  thank's

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.